# Why is this color incorrect in Sankey R plot?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, networkd3

The code below generates a Sankey diagram. However, as you can see in Figure 1, the "No Change" box is orange ("#eb6841"), not yellow ("Yellow"). This does not appear to correspond to the code, where I specified yellow as the colour I wanted. Does anyone know why it is orange and not yellow? It also looks like the box colour on the left is not always the same as the line colour, which is also wrong. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```
library(networkD3)

## create a dataframe with 12 nodes
nodes = data.frame("name" = c("Demographics",
                               "Inequality",
                               "Productivity",
                               "Urbanisation",
                               "Balance of Payments",
                               "Consumption",
                               "Debt",
                               "FDI",
                               "Trade Deals",
                               "Currency",
                               "Positive",
                               "No Change",
                               "Negative"))

## create edges with weights
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(0, 12, 2,
                                1, 11, 2,
                                2, 10, 2,
                                3, 10, 2,
                                4, 11, 2,
                                5, 10, 2,
                                6, 12, 2,
                                7, 11, 2,
                                8, 10, 2,
                                9, 11, 2
                               ), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

## set column names for links
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

## add edge types for coloring purpose

links$group <- c("group_1",
                 "group_1",
                 "group_2",
                 "group_2",
                 "group_3",
                 "group_3",
                 "group_4",
                 "group_4",
                 "group_5",
                 "group_5")

## Create custom color list using d3 for each node
node_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal() .domain(["Demographics",
                               "Inequality",
                               "Productivity",
                               "Urbanisation",
                               "Balance of Payments",
                               "Consumption",
                               "Debt",
                               "FDI",
                               "Trade Deals",
                               "Currency",
                               "Positive",
                               "No Change",
                               "Negative",
                              "group_1",
                               "group_2",
                               "group_3",
                               "group_4",
                 "group_5"]) .range(["#edc951", "#edc951", "#eb6841", "#eb6841", "#cc2a36", "#cc2a36", "#4f372d", "#4f372d", "#00a0b0", "#00a0b0", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "#edc951", "#eb6841", "#cc2a36", "#4f372d", "#00a0b0"])'

## Draw Sankey Diagram

p = sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
 Source = "source", Target = "target",
 Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
 fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 40,
 colourScale = node_color,
 LinkGroup = "group")

p
```

Figure 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The group names can not have spaces in them. It will only consider the text before the first space.